# Fluentd plugin for http with base authenticatoin

Tags: http, plugins, basic-authentication, fluentd

Is there any way to handle http request with basic authentication in Fluentd? Or any `in_http` plugin extension for that?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is putting nginx as a reverse proxy that does the authentication and then forwards the call to fluentd.

Comment: Yeah, in the end I set up apache as a reverse proxy. I had to set it up to handle a high load. Probably nginx is more suited to handle such workload, but right now apache is behaving good, so! Thanks anyway.