# add authentication to fluentd instance getting syslogs from cloud foundry application

Tags: cloud-foundry, fluentd

I have a cloud foundry application and I had a requirement to get the logs into an S3 bucket.

I followed the advice [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/fluentd.html) and have used a docker image to push onto a cloud foundry application.  Logs now go to the fluentd instance and onto S3.

The problem I have is that the fluentd instance is publicly visible and the cloud foundry provider has not implemented [this](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/cf-help.html#network-policies) so we cannot enable container communication.

I can do this

`curl -X POST -d 'json={"foo":"bar"}' https://fluentd.my.domain`

And it will record a log.

Is there anyway I can somehow limit traffic to the fluentd instance.

I don't see how I can add a custom header or anything when cloud foundry is sending the syslog.

Comment: Your link shows it is accepting syslog input over TCP/UDP but your curl command is trying to push data over HTTP protocol. Question is, are you using syslog input or http input at fluentd source?.
Can you paste your fluentd full config as well?>

Comment: I am outside of work unfortunately and I do not have the config available but it is not TCP/UDP it is http.   If it is cloud foundry app to cloud foundry app then it is http.  The curl works

Comment: It appears, HTTP Input does not support any auth.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146565/fluentd-plugin-for-http-with-base-authenticatoin.
if you are using syslog input then we could enable mutual auth between your application and fluentd. Let me know if this helps then I will put it as answer with more details on secure syslog.

Comment: @Imran syslog won't work, I've been down this path before.  I had a syslog input but it would not connect.  The reason is The documentation from Cloud Foundry on sending things to Fluentd doesn't appear to be running Fluentd on Cloud Foundry which is why it's talking regular syslog.

Currently, anything expecting requests on our cloud foundry provider must be talking HTTP.  I've clarified this with the support

Comment: When I changed from syslog input to the http input then it worked for the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you expose fluentd as another app on CF over TCP port?. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/enabling-tcp-routing.html .
After that we can easily enable mutual auth over TLS. Please correct me if I mis-stated anything.